# Devel::Peek Question

Tags: perl, peek

```
% perl -Ilib -MDevel::Peek -le '$a="34567"; $a=~s/...//; Dump($a)' 
SV = PV(0x8171048) at 0x8186f48   # replaced "12345" with "34567"
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,OOK,pPOK)
  OFFSET = 3
  PV = 0x8181bdb ( "34\003" . ) "67"\0
  CUR = 2
  LEN = 9
```

<strike>Where do the 2 zeros in the chomped part `( "12\003" . )` between `2` and `3` come from?</strike>

Why do I get this kind of output in the chomped part `( "34\003" . )`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bug?  "\003" is chr(3) in octal form.  However:

```
$ perl -Ilib -MDevel::Peek -le '$a="12345"; $a=~s/...//; Dump($a)'
SV = PVIV(0x869b0bc) at 0x86a5060
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,OOK,pPOK)
  IV = 3  (OFFSET)
  PV = 0x869fac3 ( "123" . ) "45"\0
  CUR = 2
  LEN = 5
```

I can't duplicate that; what version of perl are you using?

Note that the part of the string buffer in () is reserved but not currently in use.

Comment: `This is perl 5, version 14, subversion 1 (v5.14.1) built for i686-linux`. Devel::Peek version = 1.07

Answer (score 1):

I am getting same result as sid_com using perl 5.12.2 on Windows. However the string length is taken from `CUR` field of structure anyway. I don't see why this should be a bug, there can be any bytes in rest of string buffer.

Comment: To me it looks like that instead of the last character there is the length in octal.

Comment: @sid_com - but the length is just two, not three. It could be the offset, though.

Comment: When I chop off 9 characters I get a `\t`.

Comment: I accepted ysth's answer because it matches better with [perlguts/Offsets](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html#Offsets)

Comment: Maybe the `\t` because `perl -E 'say ord "\t"'` = 9.